# Dart variable not final warning

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have written this code below to make an `Icon` `Stateful` inside a `Stateless` widget.

```
class IconState extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isSelected;

  IconState({
    this.isSelected,
  });

  _IconState state; // this is not final because I need to assign it below

  void toggle() {
    state.change();
  }

  @override
  _IconState createState() => state = new _IconState(
        isSelected: this.isSelected,
      );
}

class _IconState extends State<IconState> {
  _IconState({
    this.isSelected,
  });

  bool isSelected = false;

  Widget _unSelected = Icon(
    null,
  );

  Widget _selected = Icon(
    Icons.check_outlined,
    color: Colors.red,
  );

  void change() {
    setState(() {
      this.isSelected = this.isSelected == true ? false : true;
    });
  }

  Icon evaluate() {
    if (isSelected) {
      return _selected;
    }
    return _unSelected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return evaluate();
  }
}
```

To update the state of the Icon, I call the `toggle()` method from my Stateless widget.

Dart is giving me a non-final instance warning inside an @immutable class, but I am unable to find a workaround for this.

I have tried following:

```
final _IconState state = new _IconState(
    isSelected: this.isSelected, // throws an error => Invalid reference to 'this' expression.
  );
```

also this, but doesn't work either

```
final _IconState state;

IconState({this.isSelected}) {
  this.state = new _IconState(
    isSelected: this.isSelected,
  );
};
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you want to stick with setState StatefulWidget, you have to move the state to the highest position Widget which needs access to the state. In your case the StatelessWidget that is able to call `toggle()`. If not, you need to learn other state management solutions like @Scott Godfrey 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the isSelected boolean inside an external state management class, then you can return 2 separate widgets in response to the change.  Otherwise you would have to change the state inside of the widget where the icon will be displayed.  Something like this:

```
class IconState extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isSelected;
  //any other needed state

  bool get isSelected => _isSelected;

  void changeIsSelected(bool selected) {
    _isSelected = selected;
    notifyListeners();
  }
 }
```

Then use ChangeNotifierProvider to to inject the state and call the change method.

```
final iconStateProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => IconState());
```

Now, you can use iconStateProvider to access the state and methods.  You will need a Builder or Consumer widget to listen for changes to the state.

```
  Consumer( builder: (context, watch, child) {
    final iconState = watch(iconStateProvider);
    if (iconState.isSelected) {
      return Icon();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

This is using the Riverpod library, which is only 1 of many external state management libraries.   I recommend watching tutorials on YouTube on different libraries and pick one that best suits you.

Comment: too vague to understand for me with the experience I have. Could your provide some examples?

Comment: I tried putting the Consumer as a child in a container. But I need to change the IconState onTap of the parent element, and I cannot do that from iconStateProvider alone. What should I do?

Comment: You can wrap the parent container with the Consumer widget.  Notice it allows you to assign a child also. It depends on what needs to be rebuilt based on state changes.

Comment: I also had to define ChangeNotifierProvider up in the hierarchy.